# How to iterate through all Contentresolver entries?

Tags: android, android-cursor, android-contentresolver

I have a database in my app, which I fill with data and an ID.
Then I request the database with the ID's I want:

```
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uriPath, null, "ID = ?", new String[]{id1, id2, etc.}, null);
```

This retrieves me a cursor with all requested ID's .

**How can I retrieve all objects in my UriPath ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enter the **Uri** and leave the rest **null**

```
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uriPath, null, null, null, null);
```